# How can I use methods in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

That's probably not the clearest title ..

Essentially, what I want to do is run the path (e.g. '/sexypage') through a function, which will do some AR lookups. If a match is found, that function will handle a redirect, which is no problem, but if not I want the routes file to carry on looking for a match as normal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually done in `before_action` of a controller

Answer (score 0):

As @Ix00st says this is normally done via a controller.  You can't have complicated logic or DB lookups in your routes.  Any data-dependent requests should go to standard urls like /sexypage/:some_param